# Why does my interscroller format not click?

Tags: css, ads

I built a ad format for my website and it works well but I am unable to click the actual ad element.  It seems the layering / positioning I have used to achieve the affect, does not allow my to click the elements that need to be clicked i.e. the actual ad.

Below is the main html that positions the ad with some inline css

```
    <div id="inter-outer" class="interscroller-wrapper" style="height: 667px; right: 14.7031px; width: 375px;">
   <div id="intscdiv" class="interscroller-bg-wrapper" style="height: 667px; right: 0px; clip: rect(0px 375px 677px 0px); width: 375px;">
      <div id="nxtads" class="interscroller-bg" style="height: 667px; width: 375px; padding: 0px; overflow: hidden; text-align: center;">
         <div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);font-weight: bold;margin: auto;padding: 0px;text-align: center;font-family: arial;width: 320px;/* display: none; */">ADVERTISEMENT</div>
         <div id="smt-130304454" style="margin: 0px auto;width: 320px;height: 480px;/* position: absolute; *//* z-index: 1000000000; */">
            <a href="http://google.com">
                <img src="https://support.inmobi.com/ui/uploads/Interstitial-1.png" width="320" height="480"/>
            </a>
        </div>
         <div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);font-weight: bold;margin: 0px;padding: 0px;text-align: center;font-family: arial;position: fixed;width: 375px;bottom: 20px;/* display: none; */">SCROLL TO CONTINUE</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Below is some external css that is included.

```
.interscroller-wrapper {
    position: relative !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
    background: #ffffff !important;
    z-index:10000000 !important;
}

.interscroller-bg-wrapper {
    position: absolute !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    left:0 !important;
}

.interscroller-bg {
    position: fixed !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    top: 2% !important;
    backface-visibility: hidden !important;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden !important;
    border:0 !important;
 }
```

Here is a js fiddle with demo https://jsfiddle.net/kw80z7cL/

I cant work it out.

Comment: do you want your ad to appear above your page, like the content of page will be visible once it hide? Or you want your ad appear between / with other contents in your page?

Comment: check the jsfiddle demo. I want to exactly as is, but so the ad is clickable. You can see that when trying to click the ad, you are actually clicking the elements above not the actual ad